# Unable to access ActiveMQ using JMS based code and amqp 1.0

Tags: java, activemq-classic, amqp

I'm trying to connect to an ActiveMQ broker using AMQP 1.0, but I want to use JMS within my application code. I'm interested in using JMS primarily because I want developers to be able to use API's that they are already familiar with.

I have ActiveMQ 5.14.0 running on localhost and the following code :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        // Producer
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("amqp://localhost:5672");

        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();     

        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                                                   Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Topic topic = session.createTopic("customerTopic");     

        // Publish
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Message msg = session.createTextMessage("Task : " + i);

            producer.send(msg);

        }
        session.close();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }

    }


}
```

The code always fails in the same way, with the following root cause in the stacktrace :

`Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too (>30000) long: tcp://127.0.0.1:5672`

This happens on the `connection.start()` method call.

If I run the same code against the ActiveMQ tcp endpoint then it executes as expected.

My pom file dependencies are as follows ( and I suspect that this is the root of my problem as I find the documentation of dependencies extremely hard to follow )

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms</artifactId>
        <version>0.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My immediate question is "Why doesn't this work?".

My supplementary ( opinion based ) question is "Is it worthwhile trying to use the JMS abstraction above AMQP 1.0, or should I just abandon myself to learning the provider specific APIs?"

Comment: Hopefully the above code snippet is just wrong, you appear to be using the ActiveMQ native client to try and connect to the AMQP transportConnector address which will never work as the native client uses OpenWire as its protocol.

Comment: @tim bish : i think it was wrong on a number of levels :). I have it working now by updating my dependencies and altering the way the connection Factory is created. It seems that i was expecting ( hoping ) that the ActiveMQConnectionFactory would create the correct implementation based on the URL i pass to the constructor. Once I figured out it didn't then things got easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is better to work with jndi

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, InterruptedException, NamingException {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("connectionfactory.myFactoryLookup",
                "amqp://localhost:5672");
        props.put("topic." + "MyTOPIC", "customerTopic");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
        ConnectionFactory cf1 = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("myFactoryLookup");
        Topic topic = (Topic) ic.lookup("MyTOPIC");
        connection = cf1.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
        connection.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Message msg = session.createTextMessage("Task : " + i);
            producer.send(msg);
        }
        session.close();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

replace

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
    <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms</artifactId>
    <version>0.32</version>
</dependency>
```

by

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

on the broker side you need to add:

```
 <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?transport.transformer=jms"/>
```

ref http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html

Comment: Am I missing something - it looks like you are saying replace the jms client with itself ...

Comment: This code works, but I'm a little concerned that it _may_ be using an older version of the AMQP spec. I confess that I have no idea how to tell, other than that there are qpid-amqp-1-0-client libraries available.

Comment: Qpid JMS is a complete AMQP 1.0 Java Message Service 1.1 client built using Qpid Proton.
http://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html

Comment: Qpid JMS (AMQP 1.0) ^ qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-0.32-bin.tar.gz ASC, MD5, SHA1
**We recommend you try our newer Qpid JMS AMQP 1.0 client.**
https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.32/